# Convert TDMS-File to XLSX

Tags: python, excel

I would like to convert a folder full of TDMS files 1:1 to XLSX.

Since important is that the Excel file has the same tabs as the TDMS file and the same file name.

I get the tabs read and the file names, but I don't know how to create new Excel files with the same names and content as the TDMS. Thats what i have tried so far:

```
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from nptdms import tdms
import os,glob

#Namen aller TDMS-Dateien in einem Ordner
file_names=glob.glob('*.tdms')

for file in glob.glob("*.tdms"):
    tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(file)
    tdms_groups = tdms_file.groups()
    print(tdms_groups)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i found out, how to save each TDMS-File as XLSX,

```
import os, xlsxwriter,glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from nptdms import TdmsFile
from nptdms import tdms

file_names=glob.glob('*.tdms')
    

# Read the files back into a dataframe
dataframe_list = []
for file in glob.glob("*.tdms"):
    tdms_file = TdmsFile.read(file)
    df = tdms_file['Line 1'].as_dataframe()
    dataframe_list.append(df)
    file = file.replace(".tdms", "")
    df.to_excel(str(file)+".xlsx")
```

But the problem is i have to know the path name ( Line 1 in this case).

I want to find out the path or group names, to save the XLSX File with alle tabs and the same name as in the original TDMS-File.

So can someone tell me how to read the individual tab names before opening the file and then create an XLSX file with the same number of tabs, the same tab name and content?

Edit:
When i use the command tdms_file.groups() i´ll get the following output:

```
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Line 1'>, <TdmsGroup with path /'Current_Line 1'>]
```

, but i can´t just get the tab names only ( "Line 1" and "Current Line 1"). After that i want to create an XLSX-File with the tab "Line 1" and the tab "Current Line 1" with the same content.